# JavaScript overriding href llinks

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 images used for a button, I shall call them IA, IB, and IC.

And 4 functions. MouseOver, MouseOff, MouseDown, MouseUp

- IA loads on the page as default image with zindex of 100
- IB loads on the page with zindex of 89
- IC loads on the page with zindex of 10

Js meaning

> IA = {on MouseOver IA zindex changes from 100 to 1}
>
> IB = {on MouseOff IA zindex changes from 1 to 100 : on MouseDown IC zindex changes from 10 to 120}
>
> IC = {on MouseDown IC zindex changes from 10 to 120 : on MouseUp IC zindex changes from 120 to 10}

When I use these functions (mainly the IC function) the href in the `<a>` classes no longer work and it dose not navigate to the new page. How can I make it so on mouse click it navigates to the new page?

The full code including Html, JavaScript and CSS can be found here: http://jsbin.com/casoy/2/edit?html,css,js,console,output

```
A=""
function mouseover1() {
    document.getElementById(A).style.zIndex="1"
}
function mouseoff1() {
    document.getElementById(A).style.zIndex="100"
}
function mouseclick1() {
    document.getElementById(A).style.zIndex="120"
}
function mouseunclick1() {
    document.getElementById(A).style.zIndex="1"
}
```

A full preview with buttons can be seen live at http://officialacescottie.co.uk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This effect could be done with CSS only, without any JavaScript. Try it http://jsbin.com/casoy/8/edit